# How to disable Rails request INFO logs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

Using Rails 6, I am trying to stop logging requests into our server:

`Started GET "/statistics/all_metrics?start=%222021-12-05T00:00:00.000Z%22&end=%222021-12-05T23:59:59.999Z%22&publisher_id=0" for 134.238.130.205 at 2021-12-05 10:49:28 +0000`

Just to clarify - all the `Started *` logs.

They are all in `INFO` level.

I am unable to understand who produces that - PUMA? RACK? If so, how can I shut this off.

Thank you

Comment: You don't want any logs at all?

Comment: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#log-levels. Try with :warn. Is this what you need?

Comment: I don't want them to be in INFO, however I still want :info level in my app

Comment: @Himberjack any luck? same issue for me